Conda list shows a geopandas package but cannot import it python 12
Trying to setup separate environments for different versions of python.  conda list in Anaconda Prompt shows the packages is installed in that environment, but then I can't import it.  Using Jupyter Notebook.

Python 3.12.3
conda 24.5.0
my environment envdm_py12
package in question: geopandas
Windows



can you show the output of conda list geopandas

Sure.
geopandas, 0.14.4, pyhd8ed1ab_0, conda-forge;
geopandas-base, 0.14.4, pyha770c72_0, conda-forge

"conda list in Anaconda Prompt shows the packages is installed in that environment". What does %conda list run in the notebook show though? You are confusing environments it seems. If you cannot import it, then it isn't installed in that environment where the active kernel is running. %conda list run in the notebook  should better reflect the environment where the kernel is running. (You probably didn't connect things the way you think you did, see here, as well as the other high scoring answers there.) ...

 See more about the modern %conda command for running in cells of active notebooks here. The magic versions ensure you are addressing the environment in which the kernel is running.

%conda env list has been giving me a error: incomplete escape \U at position 28.  Would !conda env list be a better approch?

What does print(sys.executable) in your notebook print?

print(sys.executable) points to my C:\Users\me\anaconda3\python.exe
